# Managing UITableView with multiple segmented controls

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to make it so that if any of the segmented controls change, the apply button at the top becomes enabled. I also need to be able to access each one's value. I am using Swift. Here is what it looks like:

[image: iOS Simulator Screenshot]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please post the code where you've attempted to achieve this...

Answer (score 1):

```
I assume you must have subclass of your UITableViewCell. If you don't have make subclass of UITableViewCell

In subclass
1. Create as weak property of UISegementControl
2. Create protocol
protocol TableViewCellDelegate
{
 func segmentSelected(sender:UISegmentControl)
}
3. create delegate as weak refrence for protocol

In Interface Builder
1. link your UISegementControl to your UITableViewController
2. link your delegate to your UITableViewController

In UITableViewController

func segmentSelected(sender:UISegmentControl)
{
  // here you get value changed segment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your cell you can add an event listener for the segmented control:

```
[cell.segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

You can handle which segmented control changed with the parameter in the method below

```
-(void)action:(UISegmentedControl*)sender
```

If you really need to have access to all segmented controls at all time then perhaps you can maintain a dictionary with all the segmented control, with they key being the indexPath or some other unique property of each row. Then when you instantiate the cell you set the segmented control on the dictionary

EDIT: sorry I dind´t realise you were using swift, I believe the above code shoud be the following in swift:

```
      cell.segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: "action:", forControlEvents: .EventValueChanged)



      func action(sender:UISegmentedControl){}
```